# Share on iOS through Facebook App not working

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, fbdialogs

Using FBDialogs and the the sample code from Facebook dev only works when you don't have the Facebook App installed.
When I test on my device and I try to share, the app send me to Facebook App with the dialog box, aparently with all the information correctly, after publish, FB app send me back to my app as expected, but nothing was published. No errors or results logged from handler.

Forcing the not installed facebook app method, works fine.

Anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.. did you find the reason? It's annoying... Thanks

Comment: I also have the same issue. Anyone solved this problem ?

Comment: Same here, anyone managed to solve this?